# Como tirar a transparência da imagem e dos input text e deixar o fundo do forms transparente

Tags: html, css, java-ee

Bom dia, queria apenas deixar o apenas o fundo do formulário mais transparente mas ele altera tudo que esta dentro, alguém tem alguma dica ? obrigado...

```
<h:body>
    <p:growl id="mensagem" />
    <p:messages autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
    <p:dialog header="" closable="false" draggable="false"
        resizable="false" modal="true" visible="true" style="opacity: 0.5">

        <form>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <h5>
                        <h:graphicImage url="../resources/images/contato9.png"
                            align="left" />
                    </h5>

                    <td><p:messages autoUpdate="true" closable="true" /> <h:panelGrid
                            columns="1">

                            <div class="submit-line" style="opacity: inherit;">
                                <button class="submit-lente" type="submit">
                                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                </button>
                                <h2>
                                    <p:inputMask id="cpf" mask="999.999.999-99" size="17"
                                        placeholder="CPF" required="true"
                                        requiredMessage="O campo CPF é obrigatório"
                                        value="#{MBFuncionarios.funcionario.cpf}" />
                                </h2>
                            </div>

                            <div class="submit-line" style="opacity: 1">
                                <button class="submit-lente" type="submit">
                                    <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                                </button>
                                <p:password id="senha" maxlength="15" size="17"
                                    placeholder="Senha" required="true"
                                    requiredMessage="O campo Senha é obrigatório"
                                    value="#{MBFuncionarios.funcionario.senha}" />
                            </div>
                            <br />

                            <h:commandButton value="Entrar" class="btn btn-outline-dark"
                                style="width: 205px; height: 40px" update=":mensagem"
                                actionListener="#{MBFuncionarios.autenticar}" />

                        </h:panelGrid></td>

                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </p:dialog>
</h:body>
```

[image: Login]

Comment: Insira somente na sua classe CSS que exibe a sua imagem de fundo, e elimina dos demais. Ex: background: url('path/sua/imagem.jpg'); opacity: 0.5;filter: alpha(opacity=50);

Comment: Mas eu quer deixar a imagem normal e colocar transparencia no resto

Comment: Explique melhor sua pergunta, se puder editá-la disponibilizando apenas o HTML processado no código fonte, e com o link para a imagem do fundo, e rabiscar somente o que quer transparente em um print, assim fica ágil te ajudar.